# Finding the index of one element randomly chosen from np.array elements that match a condition

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

Consider the numpy array, `arr1`, shown below.

```
arr1 = np.array([-8,-3,-5,-2, 8,-4],
                [ 7, 4, 3, 1,-5, 6],  
                [-6, 1,-2,-6,-4,-8],
                [ 5,-2, 7,-5,-3,-1]]) 

row_idx = 2
val = -6
```

**I want to randomly select the index of one value (ie: -6) from the specified row index (ie: 2).**   I started by isolating the target values:

```
arr2 = np.where(arr1[row_idx][:] == val)
print(arr2)
```

This correctly produces the desired indices:   `(array([0, 3)], dtype=int64,)`

I'm a new enough coder that I'm having trouble **randomly selecting either the 0 or the 3**.  What is an efficient way to do this?  (the actual arr1 is much larger).

Thanks

Comment: `np.random.choice(arr2[0])`

Comment: Yes, of course.  Thanks, Trenton_M